# Is there a way to get continuous radial/polar coordinates?

Tags: node-editor, geometry, procedural, mathematics

I'm not exactly sure if that's the right word for it, but basically, I want to be able to generate a gradient around a point like in my picture, but without the seam. the only thing I can think of like that is a color wheel, where it continuously loops around. My goal is to use a math -> compare node to make a triangle shape emanating from the center, one that you can change what direction it's facing and how wide it is. My problem is that with the gradient I have, the triangle shape disappears over the seam (I can better display what I mean in a video, I linked one in the comments). I want the triangle shape to be able to circle around in any direction indefinitely

[image].

[image: The node setup for my gradient]

Comment: https://youtu.be/cL6n3W0pxsc my issue

Comment: Why don't you make use of the "rotation" parameter of your mapping-node?

Comment: im baffled that i didn't realize that

Comment: This actually solved more problems then i realized

Answer (score 4):

You *could* avoid doing the trigonometric stuff the *Gradient > Radial* node has already done for you, by, instead of *avoiding* the discontinuity at 0, *using* it as the start of your segment:

[image]

At its most primitive, the start-angle is measured out of 1, clockwise from 9 o'clock, and the segment is anticlockwise from there.This set-up works round the clock, through negative and >1 start-angles.

But I guess the disadvantage is the amount of plumbing you have to do to wrangle the interface into offering you center of arc, angle of arc, in degrees, clockwise from 12 o'clock:

[image]

(Maybe there are ways of cutting this down?) ... anyway, that's quite a few nodes to avoid one trig. calculation per shading point. Given modern kit, this is probably old-fashioned :)

**Edit:**

It may be better to forget the *Radial* altogether and roll-your-own:

[image]

.. which is added to the .blend:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mr Bestt. Can you confirm that gradient node does not use trig things?

Comment: Hi, Clu.. oops!.. @lemon.. No, I'm suggesting the Gradient node _does_ do trig, and you could avoid doing it _again_. On second thoughts, why not get rid of the Gradient altogether and do our own trig, and  dot-product? I'll edit..

Answer (score 3):

Very close to your settings:

[image]

- Use the rotation of the mapping node to rotate
- Get an absolute value to get ride of the seam
- Change the map range in consequence
- Use a color ramp to tune the width of the angle
- Eventually change the color ramp mode to *"constant"* to have a sharp transition